# IP-restricted port forwarding with iptables

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

For an example, I have two authorized client computers, 1.1.1.1 and 2.1.1.1.  My server running iptables is 3.1.1.1 and my firewalled web server is 4.1.1.1.  When one of the authorized client IPs connects to 3.1.1.1 on port 80, I would like the connection to be forwarded to 4.1.1.1 on port 8888.  If any other IP attempts to connect I would like it to refuse/drop the connection.  What iptables config would accomplish this?  Is there something more specific out there that would be better suited for this job?

Answer (score 2):

The forwarding can be done with [DNAT](http://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//NAT-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.2). Just give a specific source address, and let the others be rejected/dropped as normal.